# Get Parent directory of a specific path in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I have full file path in a variable of batch file. How to get its first and second level parent directory path?

```
set path=C:\SecondParent\FirstParent\testfile.ini
```

Comment: Will %~dppath% work? I know it works for numbered args (%~dp1).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

do not use variable [PATH](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) for this. %PATH% is a built-in variable used by the command prompt.

```
@echo off
set "_path=C:\SecondParent\FirstParent\testfile.ini"
for %%a in ("%_path%") do set "p_dir=%%~dpa"
echo %p_dir%
for %%a in (%p_dir:~0,-1%) do set "p2_dir=%%~dpa"
echo %p2_dir%
```

Comment: its giving its first parent directory. But i need it grant parent directory too. How to get this?

Comment: hi both printing same value.

Comment: @SelvakumarGurusamy - fixed

Comment: I would change the second `for` loop to this: `for /D %%a in ("%p_dir%..") do set "p2_dir=%%~dpa"`; you are removing the trailing backslash, which might be problematic in case the first-level parent is already the root of a drive, because the loop would receive e. g. `D:`, which means the current directory of drive `D:`; my suggestion returns the root of drive `D:`...

Answer (score 9):

As npocmaka correctly suggests, pick a different variable from `%PATH%` (or [any of these other environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)).  Secondly, make sure your script uses `setlocal` to avoid junking up your console session's environment with the variables in this script.  Thirdly, just add a `\..` for each ancestor you want to navigate.  No need to bother with substring manipulation.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "dir=C:\SecondParent\FirstParent\testfile.ini"
for %%I in ("%dir%\..\..") do set "grandparent=%%~fI"
echo %grandparent%
```

Comment: yes i understood. thanks for your valuable information.

Comment: nice. `\..` is clearer than cryptic DOS syntax e.g. `%varname:~0,-1%`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the file first parent (base dir) using a small subroutine that returns a `~dp` path to a file,  `:GetFileBaseDir` and `:GetFileBaseDirWithoutEndSlash` in the example below.

Thank to @rojo for a way to achive the goal for multiple parents. I've enveloped his solution in a subroutine `:GetDirParentN` to make it more useful.

```
@echo off
    setlocal
REM Initial file path
    set "pathTestFile=C:\SecondParent\FirstParent\testfile.ini"
    echo pathTestFile:              "%pathTestFile%"

REM First level parent (base dir)
    REM with ending backslash
    call :GetFileBaseDir dirFileBase "%pathTestFile%"
    echo dirFileBase:               "%dirFileBase%"

    REM Same but without ending backslash
    call :GetFileBaseDirWithoutEndSlash dirFileBaseWithBackSlash "%pathTestFile%"
    echo dirFileBaseWithBackSlash:  "%dirFileBaseWithBackSlash%"

    echo.

REM Based on @rojo answer, using subroutine
    REM One level up
    call :GetDirParentN dirFileParent1 "%pathTestFile%" ".."
    echo dirFileParent1:            "%dirFileParent1%"


    REM Two levels up
    call :GetDirParentN dirFileParent2 "%pathTestFile%" "..\.."
    echo dirFileParent2:            "%dirFileParent2%"


    REM Three levels up
    call :GetDirParentN dirFileParent3 "%pathTestFile%" "..\..\.."
    echo dirFileParent3:            "%dirFileParent3%"

    exit /b 0


:GetFileBaseDir
    :: sets the value to dirFileBase variable
    set "%~1=%~dp2"
    exit /b 0


:GetFileBaseDirWithoutEndSlash
    set "dirWithBackSlash=%~dp2"
    REM substring from the start to the end minus 1 char from the end
    set "%~1=%dirWithBackSlash:~0,-1%"
    exit /b 0


:GetDirParentN
    for %%I in ("%~2\%~3") do set "%~1=%%~fI"
    exit /b 0
```

The output:

```
pathTestFile:              "C:\SecondParent\FirstParent\testfile.ini"
dirFileBase:               "C:\SecondParent\FirstParent\"
dirFileBaseWithBackSlash:  "C:\SecondParent\FirstParent"

dirFileParent1:            "C:\SecondParent\FirstParent"
dirFileParent2:            "C:\SecondParent"
dirFileParent3:            "C:\"
```